# Customize word right click menu

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code to customize the right click menu:

```
Sub CreateMenuItem()
        Dim MenuButton As CommandBarButton
        With CommandBars("Text") 'Text, Lists and Tables
            Set MenuButton = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            With MenuButton
                .Caption = "Correct"
                .Style = msoButtonCaption
                .OnAction = "InsertCorrect"
            End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

It works fine with text and lists, but only partially with tables:

With CommandBars("Tables")

I must select the whole table or a column then it works but not inside a cell. What is the name for the context menu inside a cell or for text inside a table cell?

Answer (score 0):

I made this routine to see al the names of the CommandBars in Word:

```
Sub ListYourCommandBars()
    For Each c In CommandBars
        Debug.Print c.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Good news they are already sorted alphabetically. I found one called `Table Cells`. I tried it:

```
With CommandBars("Table Cells")
```

and it worked. Only thing, a cell or a number of cells must be "wholly selected". That is, the menu-item doesnt show up if you just enter inside the cell, you must select the cell "as a whole" (dunno how to say it better). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work inside a table cell by adding the MenuButton to the following Built-In CommandBars: "Text", "Linked Text", "Table Text", "Font Paragraph", "Linked Headings", "Linked Table", "Linked Text", "Lists", "Table Cells", "Table Lists", "Tables", "Tables and Borders", and "Text Box".
I’m not sure which one actually did the trick.  Here’s my code:

```
Private DisableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub UpdateRightClickMenus()

    Dim MenuButton As CommandBarButton
    Dim CommandBarTypes(100) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim PRChecklistIsSelected As Boolean
    Dim CheckListTypeFound As Boolean
    PRChecklist = True

    ResetRightClickMenus

    CommandBarTypes(0) = "Text"
    CommandBarTypes(1) = "Linked Text"
    CommandBarTypes(2) = "Table Text"
    CommandBarTypes(3) = "Font Paragraph"
    CommandBarTypes(4) = "Linked Headings"
    CommandBarTypes(5) = "Linked Table"
    CommandBarTypes(6) = "Linked Text"
    CommandBarTypes(7) = "Lists"
    CommandBarTypes(8) = "Table Cells"
    CommandBarTypes(9) = "Table Lists"
    CommandBarTypes(10) = "Tables"
    CommandBarTypes(11) = "Tables and Borders"
    CommandBarTypes(12) = "Text Box"

    Dim cc As ContentControl
    Set cc = FindContentControlByTag("ListBox_PR_TR")

    If IsNull(cc) Then
        DisableEvents = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Find Selected
    For i = 1 To cc.DropdownListEntries.Count
        If cc.Range.Text = "Product Review" Then
            PRChecklistIsSelected = True
            CheckListTypeFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
        If cc.Range.Text = "Technical Review" Then
            PRChecklistIsSelected = False
            CheckListTypeFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If CheckListTypeFound = False Then Exit Sub

    For i = 0 To 12

        With Application

            If PRChecklistIsSelected Then

                'Add right-click menu option to set as a Product Review comment
                With .CommandBars(CommandBarTypes(i))
                    Set MenuButton = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
                    With MenuButton
                        .Caption = "Set as Product Review Comment"
                        .Style = msoButtonCaption
                        .OnAction = "Set_as_Product_Review_Comment"
                    End With
                End With

            Else

                'Add right-click menu option to set as a Tech Review comment
                With .CommandBars(CommandBarTypes(i))
                    Set MenuButton = .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
                    With MenuButton
                        .Caption = "Set as Tech Review Comment"
                        .Style = msoButtonCaption
                        .OnAction = "Set_as_Tech_Review_Comment"
                    End With
                End With

            End If

        End With

    Next i

    RightClickMenuItemsAdded = True

End Sub


Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

    If DisableEvents = True Then Exit Sub

    Set cc = FindContentControlByTag("ListBox_PR_TR")

    If IsNull(cc) Then
        ResetRightClickMenus
        DisableEvents = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cc.Range.Text = "Technical Review" Then
        Find_PR_Style_ReplaceWith_TR_Style
    End If

    UpdateRightClickMenus

    DisableEvents = False

End Sub

Private Sub Find_PR_Style_ReplaceWith_TR_Style()

    Set StylePR = ThisDocument.Styles("Product Review Style")
    Set StyleTR = ThisDocument.Styles("Technical Review Style")

    With ThisDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Style = StylePR
        With .Replacement
            .ClearFormatting
            .Style = StyleTR
        End With

        .Execute Forward:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, FindText:="", ReplaceWith:=""
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Set_as_Tech_Review_Comment()
    Set StyleTR = ThisDocument.Styles("Technical Review Style")

    With ThisDocument

        Selection.Style = StyleTR

        SetCanContinuePreviousList

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub Set_as_Product_Review_Comment()
    Set StylePR = ThisDocument.Styles("Product Review Style")

    With ThisDocument

        Selection.Style = StylePR

        SetCanContinuePreviousList

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SetCanContinuePreviousList()

    Dim lfTemp As ListFormat
    Dim intContinue As Integer
    Dim oldListNumber As Single

    Set lfTemp = Selection.Range.ListFormat
    oldListNumber = lfTemp.ListValue
    If Not (lfTemp.ListTemplate Is Nothing) Then
        intContinue = lfTemp.CanContinuePreviousList( _
        ListTemplate:=lfTemp.ListTemplate)
        lfTemp.ApplyListTemplate _
        ListTemplate:=lfTemp.ListTemplate, _
        ContinuePreviousList:=False, _
        ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList
        If lfTemp.ListValue = oldListNumber Then
            lfTemp.ApplyListTemplate _
            ListTemplate:=lfTemp.ListTemplate, _
            ContinuePreviousList:=True, _
            ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList
        End If
    End If

Set lfTemp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function FindContentControlByTag(Tag As String) As ContentControl

    For Each cc In ThisDocument.ContentControls

        If cc.Tag = Tag Then

            Set FindContentControlByTag = cc
            Exit Function

        End If

    Next

End Function

Private Sub ResetRightClickMenus()

    Dim CommandBarTypes(100) As String
    Dim i As Long

    CommandBarTypes(0) = "Text"
    CommandBarTypes(1) = "Linked Text"
    CommandBarTypes(2) = "Table Text"
    CommandBarTypes(3) = "Font Paragraph"
    CommandBarTypes(4) = "Linked Headings"
    CommandBarTypes(5) = "Linked Table"
    CommandBarTypes(6) = "Linked Text"
    CommandBarTypes(7) = "Lists"
    CommandBarTypes(8) = "Table Cells"
    CommandBarTypes(9) = "Table Lists"
    CommandBarTypes(10) = "Tables"
    CommandBarTypes(11) = "Tables and Borders"
    CommandBarTypes(12) = "Text Box"

    For i = 0 To 12

        Application.CommandBars(CommandBarTypes(i)).Reset

    Next i

    RightClickMenuItemsAdded = False
End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()

    UpdateRightClickMenus

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Close()

    ResetRightClickMenus

End Sub
```